# Translating row entries to column reading from file

Tags: vb.net

Here is my working code :

```
Dim commands() =
        {
            "stmotd -a {0}",
            "stmotd -b 15 {0}"
        }


    Dim objLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")
    'Dim getcount = objLines.Length

    Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
        For Each line In objLines
            For Each cmd In commands
                SW.WriteLine(String.Format(cmd, line))

            Next
        Next
    End Using
```

Now "say" my sObj.txt file contains the following entries"

```
WINMAC
WINPPC
WINVPN
```

The output that I'm getting with the above code is:

```
stmotd -a WINMAC
stmotd -b 15 WINMAC
stmotd -a WINPPC
stmotd -b 15 WINPPC
stmotd -a WINVPN
stmotd -b 15 WINVPN
```

But I want the output as :

```
stmotd -a WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN
stmotd -b 15 WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN
```

I know it must be very easy, but I am in need of some help here. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: (I cannot test the code right now-is from my head)

```
 Dim commands() =
    {
        "stmotd -a ",
        "stmotd -b 15 "
    }

Dim objLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")

 Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
    For Each cmd In commands
        dim com as String=cmd
        For Each line In objLines
            com=com & " " & line
        Next
      SW.WriteLine(com)
    Next
End Using
```